# Series $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\tan\frac x{2^k}}{2^{k-1} \cos\frac x{2^{k-1}}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\tan\frac x{2^k}}{2^{k-1} \cos\frac x{2^{k-1}}}$$
I am struck with calculation for this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:$$2\cot (2x)=\cot x-\tan x\\ \to \tan x=2\cot (2x)-\cot x$$so 
$$\frac{\tan\frac x{2^k}}{2^{k-1} \cos\frac x{2^{k-1}}}=\\
\frac{2\cot (2\frac x{2^k})-\cot \frac x{2^k}}{2^{k-1} \cos\frac x{2^{k-1}}}$$

Comment: @Robert Z I am trying to solve this question using above Hint but not able to proceed, i need your help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035402/calculation-of-complex-trigonometric-summation/3037970#3037970